# How to restrict textinput to accept all (including special characters) except numbers?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have a text field (for names) which must allow all characters, except Latin numbers, is this possible?

I can't think of a regex for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a key up event handler to the text field and run a replace using the regex that zombiegx mentioned.

Comment: zombiegx is the person asking the question.

Comment: yup. I guess I should pay more attention.

Comment: I'm not sure that would do it, because people would still be able to Paste numbers in there as part of clipboard content. I'd use change="" event to run a search and replace, each numbers (only 10 of them right?) by "". HTH.

Comment: Yup, exactly. The CHANGE event is definitely more appropriate.

Comment: if the string has numbers then it shouldn't be allowed in the first place, so I used a validator when submiting. thanx all

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't really thought this thru

^[0-9]

... >_>